# Errors doing "npm -g update" after fresh node install with homebrew

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew

I am doing a fresh node install via homebrew and have not installed any other modules.
If I do a global update with 
    npm -g update
I get all those errors showing below.
WHat's wrong?

```
$ npm -g update
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/1.4.6
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/1.4.6
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: Refusing to delete: /usr/local/bin/npm not in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! error rolling back     at clobberFail (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.26/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/gently-rm.js:57:12)
npm ERR! error rolling back     at next (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.26/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/gently-rm.js:43:14)
npm ERR! error rolling back     at /usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.26/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/gently-rm.js:52:12
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! error rolling back  npm@1.4.6 { [Error: Refusing to delete: /usr/local/bin/npm not in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm] code: 'EEXIST', path:     '/usr/local/bin/npm' }
npm ERR! Refusing to delete: /usr/local/bin/npm not in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
File exists: /usr/local/bin/npm
Move it away, and try again. 

npm ERR! System Darwin 13.1.0
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.26/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "-g" "update"
npm ERR! cwd /usr/local
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/npm
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /usr/local/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: try appending sudo:    sudo npm -g update

Comment: sudo npm -g update shows the same errors.

Comment: yes, it does, was just a guess. The real problem is that if installed through homebrew, the npm cannot update itself. Look into my answer supplied for more details

Comment: Check out [Fixing npm On Mac OS X for Homebrew Users](https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, not sure if it helps you, but there is an issue on github: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/22408

Many would suggest download node.js from official side, instead of using Homebrew. Choice is yours of course.

Comment: I second that, install via the DMG on nodejs.org.

Comment: Or install via `nvm` to avoid global installs, which can be harder to manage.

Comment: The only thing which worked for me was the suggestion below:
brew install node --without-npm
;
curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh